# Fire Event When User is Idle, Not Working on Firefox Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have this code for checking if user is active or not in page. But not working on Firefox once you leave your cursor in page. It seems the mouseover still triggered. But perfectly working on Chrome.

```
idleTimer = null;
idleState = false;
idleWait = 2000;

(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('*').bind('mousemove keydown scroll', function () {        
        clearTimeout(idleTimer);                    
        if (idleState == true) {                 
            // Reactivated event
            $("body").append("<p>Welcome Back.</p>");            
        }

        idleState = false;            
        idleTimer = setTimeout(function () {                 
            // Idle Event
            $("body").append("<p>You've been idle for " + idleWait/1000 + " seconds.</p>");
            idleState = true; }, idleWait);
        });

    $("body").trigger("mousemove");    
  });
}) (jQuery)
```

Following this tutorial link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fire-event-when-user-is-idle/

Please help on how to fix this on Firefox Browser.
Thank you :)

Comment: I am not sure off hand, but what if you possibly added a way to check coordinates of the mouse position to window, and in the timer interval that checks for the moving event, also check if coordinates have not changed. That may get around this if it is a bug in Firefox. Sorry it is not an answer, but just a thought to try until you can find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I'm doing it with Ruby on Rails.
I put the file in assets/javascripts directory.
Finally solved it by adding it to required js in application.js like:

```
//= require js_file
```

And, important to removed the jquery document function, because it will cause the same error in Firefox. Add ONLY the main js code to file, it will be loaded automatically.:

**Important to Remove:**
    (function ($) {});
    $(document).ready(function () {});

And, at the bottom of code, add like:

```
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:load", ready);
```

Now, both Chrome and Firefox works well.